# How can I split subnodes in new Elements

Tags: xslt, xpath, nodes, xslt-grouping

I'm currently struggling with this Problem:

I have this XML:

```
<deflist>

<term>Lorem Ipsum</term>
<def>
    <para>Lorem ipsum</para>
</def>

...

<term>Lorem ipsum</term>
<def> 
    <para>Lorem ipsum 1</para>
    <para>Lorem ipsum 2</para>
    <para>Lorem ipsum 3</para>
</def>

...
</deflist>
```

Now I need to transform it into this following Structure. 
My main Problem is now that the `<term>` and `<def>`-Elements have no "Container" which i could use to match to make the `<SynonymGroups Stem="true">` Element.

```
<Synonyms>
   <SynonymGroups Stem="true">
    <Word>Lorem ipsum</Word>  -->former <term>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum</Word> -->former <def>
   </SynonymGroups>

...

   <SynonymGroups Stem="true">
    <Word>Lorem ipsum</Word>  -->former <term>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 1</Word> -->former <def>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 2</Word> -->former <def>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 3</Word> -->former <def>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 4</Word> -->former <def>
   </SynonymGroups>

</Synonyms>
```

My current Script looks like This

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//deflist"/>
</Synonyms>
</xsl:template>
```

to match the deflist..

```
<xsl:template match="term ">
  <xsl:element name="SynonymGroups">
    <xsl:attribute name="Stem">true</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:element name="Word">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

to match the `term` and make `<word>` `<SynonymGroups>`

```
<xsl:template match="def" >
    <xsl:for-each select="para"> 
      <xsl:element name="Word">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

and finally the template for the `<def>`  `<para>` Elements.

If i run this stylesheet I (naturally) get the wrong output.

Like this:

```
   <SynonymGroups Stem="true">
    <Word>Lorem ipsum</Word>  -->former <term>
   </SynonymGroups>

    <Word>Lorem ipsum 1</Word> -->former <def>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 2</Word> -->former <def>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 3</Word> -->former <def>
    <Word>Lorem ipsum 4</Word> -->former <def>
```

I can't figure out how to include the former `<def>` Elements inside the `<SynonymGroups>` element.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you know it is a grouping problem then you can use a grouping approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="deflist/def" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::term[1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="deflist">
        <Synonyms>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
        </Synonyms>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="term">
        <SynonymGroups Stem="true">
            <Word>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Word>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', generate-id())/para"/>
        </SynonymGroups>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <Word>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Word>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7m1